# Convert any number to corresponding word

Tags: numbering, conversion, programming

This is a wild one: can anyone write a code that converts a number into the corresponding word? e.g.:

```
4 -> 'four'
31 -> 'thirty-one'
```

and so on. Obviously, it is not enough to build an array in which you can store the numbers and the word associated with it and then just print instead of the number the stored word. What complicates matters more, are numbers like 11 ('eleven'). I intend to use it for numbering equations. So, anybody up to it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the `fmtcount` package to achieve that:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}

4: \numberstringnum{4}

31: \numberstringnum{31}

\end{document}
```

Use `\Numberstringnum` and `\NUMBERstringnum` respectively for capitalized and full-caps versions.

Comment: Concerning I18N: If `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` is in the document header, then the numbers are output in German.

Comment: @feklee and what should I do if language which I need in babel is not supported by this package? Package fmtcount Warning: No support for \numberstring for language 'lithuanian
' on input line 176.

Answer (score 19):

`fmcount` only works with numbers up to 100,000. For larger numbers, you will need to use [`numname`](http://ctan.org/pkg/numname) which borrows the code from the memoir class. From what I recall, this can deal with bigger numbers. Neither the readme nor the package documentation actually tells you what the commands to use are, so here they are:

- `\numtoname` turns a number into lowercase words (e.g. one)
- `\numtoName` as above, but the first letter is capitalised
- `\NumToName` as above but all words are capitalised
- `\ordinaltoname` turns a number into lc ordinal (e.g. first)
- `\ordinaltoName` as above but first letter capitalised
- `\OrdinalToName` as above but all words capitalised

This package seems to manage all numbers up to TeX's limit of 2147483647. (`numname` helfully informs me that this is: two billion, one hundred and forty-seven million, four hundred and eighty-three thousand, six hundred and forty-seven)

Comment: How to remove the hyphen in thirty-one?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but from looking at `numname.sty` you could try adding `\renewcommand*\tensunitsep{ }` to your preamble (below having called `numname`

Comment: How do I convert a variable's value to a word, e.g., `\numtoname{\someVar}`?

Comment: That depends how \someVar is defined and might involve some expansion shenanigans. In any case, I think that's a different question, perhaps you should ask it.

Answer (score 18):

The [moreenum](http://ctan.org/pkg/moreenum) package already does this as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\Nthwords{mycounter}}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{mycounter}{11}
\themycounter

\setcounter{mycounter}{470}
\themycounter

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Use `\nthwords` for lowercase. I think in the next version of the package, these will change to `\nwords` and `\Nwords`.

Comment: Hmmm... CTAN has a full documentation for [`fmtcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount). The same is not true for [`moreenum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moreenum). Plus `fmtcount` has more macros. Thanks anyway for your suggestion, I really appreciate you took your time to look into it!

Comment: `texdoc moreenum` gives me documentation; not sure why it's not showing up on CTAN.

Comment: `moreenum` actually uses `fmtcount` internally. The documentation doesn't show up on that CTAN page, but if you click the CTAN directory link, you get [`moreenum-testcase.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moreenum/testcase-moreenum.pdf) which also serves as documentation. In fact, the package is simple enough that basically everything you need to know is in the readme anyway...

Comment: Oh yeah. The version of `moreenum` on CTAN still has `\nwords` and `\nthwords` the wrong way round! The version on [github](https://github.com/scmbradley/moreenum) has this fixed. I will upload a new version to CTAN today. (which will also have the documentation renamed so that CTAN finds it.)

Comment: @Seamus The description for `moreenum` on CTAN still says it depends on `nth` and not `fmtcount`.

Comment: @bb010g thanks for pointing this out. the readme and documentation correctly say that `moreenum` depends on `fmtcount`, but the CTAN description is incorrect. I'll try to fix that when I have a moment.