# How to change the chapter number to display as text (One, Two, ...)?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

In LaTeX, how do I change the chapter number to display as text? eg:

CHAPTER ONE not CHAPTER 1;

CHAPTER THIRTEEN not CHAPTER 13.

Comment: Related question: [Convert any number to corresponding word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/convert-any-number-to-corresponding-word)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557900/in-latex-how-do-i-change-the-chapter-number-to-display-as-text?noredirect=1). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 20):

Short answer: put the following code before `\begin{document}`.

```
\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chaptermark}{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Change `\Numberstring` into `\numberstring` if you don't want the number name capitalized.

A longer answer requires more information from you, that you can add to your question.

A quick solution would be also

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
```

but this will have some consequences on the typesetting of the Table of Contents (but also of headers). Choosing a strategy depends on the actual needs (and also on the class used).

Comment: If you have more than 100,000 chapters, this will break. This isn't a huge problem, I don't think. But it is a limitation in `fmtcount`.

Comment: Quite a big book it would be. :) Also my package for spelling out numbers in Italian (**fmtcount**'s support for Italian is very buggy) has a limitation to 9999 for cardinal numbers and to 999 for ordinals. But one can survive it, I believe.

Comment: @egreg : How can I use your short answer (not the quick solution) with parts instead of chapters?

Comment: @ClintEastwood For parts I would go with redefining `\thepart`

Comment: Support of 99,999 chapters is more than enough, after all, some novels are only about 30,000 words.  Even if every word were in a chapter to itself, it wouldn't break

Comment: Is it possible to use other languages for \Numberstring?

Comment: @PressTilty Yes, look at the documentation of `fmtcount`

Answer (score 5):

The [`memoir` documentclass](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides this by default for some of the chapter styles. Consider reading the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf); specifically section **6.5.1. Deﬁning a chapter style** (p 83).

Alternatively, also view some of the self-created code on [Vincent Zoonekynd's LaTeX page for Chapters](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html).

Comment: The [`numname`](http://ctan.org/pkg/numname) package takes the code from the `memoir` class and makes it available separately. The documentation is non-existent, but see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/convert-any-number-to-corresponding-word/33516#33516) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `fncychap` package.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen there are other, perhaps smarter answers. BUt I spent quite some time on making this work, so I really wanted to post it. THis allows to convert any number from digits to English words, provided it has absolute value strictly less than a billion. This means it is more powerful than `fmtcount`, which, AFAIK, allows no negative numbers, and stops at 99.999. So here goes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\encount}[1]{%
    \ifnum #1>999999999%
        \errmessage{Too high number.}%
        \errhelp{The number you gave is at least a billion. I cannot count that high. Not in English, at least. Only in digits.}%
    \else
        \ifnum#1<0%
            \count9=#1%
            \multiply\count9 by -1%
            minus \poscount{\count9}%
        \else%
            \poscount{#1}%
        \fi%
   \fi}
\newcommand{\unitcount}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1zero\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\else\errmessage{WTF??}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\underhundredcount}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1zero\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\or eleven\or twelve\or thirteen\or fourteen\or fifteen\or sixteen\or seventeen\or eighteen\or nineteen\or twenty\or twenty-one\or twenty-two\or twenty-three\or twenty-four\or twenty-five\or twenty-six\or twenty-seven\or twenty-eight\or twenty-nine\or thirty\or thirty-one\or thirty-two\or thirty-three\or thirty-four\or thirty-five\or thirty-six\or thirty-seven\or thirty-eight\or thirty-nine\or fourty\or fourty-one\or fourty-two\or fourty-three\or fourty-four\or fourty-five\or fourty-six\or fourty-seven\or fourty-eight\or fourty-nine\or fifty\or fifty-one\or fifty-two\or fifty-three\or fifty-four\or fifty-five\or fifty-six\or fifty-seven\or fifty-eight\or fifty-nine\or sixty\or sixty-one\or sixty-two\or sixty-three\or sixty-four\or sixty-five\or sixty-six\or sixty-seven\or sixty-eight\or sixty-nine\or seventy\or seventy-one\or seventy-two\or seventy-three\or seventy-four\or seventy-five\or seventy-six\or seventy-seven\or seventy-eight\or seventy-nine\or eighty\or eighty-one\or eighty-two\or eighty-three\or eighty-four\or eighty-five\or eighty-six\or eighty-seven\or eighty-eight\or eighty-nine\or ninety\or ninety-one\or ninety-two\or ninety-three\or ninety-four\or ninety-five\or ninety-six\or ninety-seven\or ninety-eight\or ninety-nine \else\errmessage{WTF??}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\underthousandcount}[1]{%
    \count1=#1%
    \ifnum#1>99%
        \count7=#1%
        \divide\count1 by 100%
        \divide\count1 by 1%
        \unitcount{\count1} hundred%
         \multiply\count1 by 100%
         \advance\count7 by -\count1\relax%
         \ifnum\count7>0%
             \ and \underhundredcount{\count7}%
         \fi%
     \else%
         \underhundredcount{#1}
     \fi
}
\newcommand{\poscount}[1]{%
    \count3=#1%
    \count5=\count3%
    \ifnum\count3<1000%
        \underthousandcount{\count3}%
    \else%
        \ifnum\count3<1000000%
            \divide\count3 by 1000%
            \divide\count3 by 1%
            \underthousandcount{\count3} thousand%
            \multiply\count3 by 1000%
            \advance\count5 by -\count3%
            \count3=\count5%
            \ifnum\count5>0%
                \ifnum\count5>99,\else\ and\fi\ \underthousandcount{\count3}%
            \fi
        \else
            \divide\count3 by 1000000%
            \divide\count3 by 1%
            \underthousandcount{\count3} million%
            \multiply\count3 by 1000000%
            \advance\count5 by -\count3\relax%
            \ifnum\count5>0%
                \count3=\count5%
                \divide\count3 by 1000\relax%
                \ifnum\count5>99, \else\ and \fi%
                \ifnum\count3>0%
                    \underthousandcount{\count3} thousand%
                \fi%
                \count5=#1%
                \count3=\count5%
                \divide\count3 by 1000%
                \multiply\count3 by 1000%
                \advance\count5 by -\count3\relax%
                \ifnum\count5>0%
                    \underthousandcount{\count5}%
                \fi%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\encount{\c@section}}
\newcommand{\test}[2]{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{#1}\loop\ifnum\c@enumi<#2\item\encount{\the\c@enumi}\repeat
    \end{enumerate}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\encount{123456789}
\test{999999}{1001000}
\end{document}
```

This provides a compilable example, which shows numbers from one million to one million, one thousand, printed as a numbered list. After typesetting one hundred and twenty-three million, four hundred and fifty-six thousand, seven hundred and eighty-nine on a line by itself. The important macros are `\encount`, `\unitcount`, `\underhundredcount`, `\underthousandcount` and `\poscount`. Only the first one is to be used. The others are internals. Yes, I should use different names with @ to avoid accidental redefinition, and yes, I should use even-numbered counter registers, but hey, I have no time for such small adjustments :). The code can easily be adjusted for uppercase. Giving an option for first letter capitalization is quite tricky, and requires to create a conditional just for that. To use this for chapter numbering, the following line added to the preamble should work

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\encount{\c@chapter}}
```

Of course, it must be wrapped in `\makeatletter…\makeatother`. I haven't tested it, but it should work. Goodnight everyone and enjoy my macro :).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \Numberstring{chapter}
{20pt}
{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont\bfseries}

\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\bfseries}

\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\bfseries}

\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\bfseries}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Typically, it would be great to present the answer in form of [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to make easy for everybody try the solution in a compact form.