# KOMA-Script: Chapter Number as a Word

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

Currently I am using `scrreprt` for my document with the option `chapterprefix=true`. I wish for my chapters prefixes to be of the form: "CHAPTER ONE" as opposed to "Chapter 1".  Now, I know that `fmtcounter` and `moreenum` can convert numbers to words but am unsure how to go about formatting the prefix.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29568/how-to-change-the-chapter-number-to-display-as-text-one-two. If this does not help solve your problem, please state why by rephrasing your question appropriately via an edit.

Comment: Yep, seems to be a duplicate -- although I did not realize that chapters in KOMA worked the same way as usual chapters.

Comment: @FreddieWitherden: They work similar, however they provide more features for customizing format and spacing. So I hope the KOMA commands below are a good addition which is not covered by the other question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the question

- [How to change the chapter number to display as text (One, Two, …)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29568/how-to-change-the-chapter-number-to-display-as-text-one-two)

shows a way changing the chapter number in all places:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
```

However, this affects also cross-references, and section numbering such as poducing One.1 instead of 1.1, which is consistent could be undesired. If you would like to change the prefix and number in the headings, not changing the general presentation of the counter, you could redefine `\chapterformat`. Furthermore, if you would like to change the marks in the header in the same way, you could adjust `\chaptermarkformat`.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\Numberstring{chapter}\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\chapappifchapterprefix{\ }%
  \Numberstring{chapter}\autodot\enskip}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\label{chap:1}
This is chapter \ref{chap:1}.
\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\end{document}​
```