# Get chapter numbers as text in the report class

Tags: pdftex, page-numbering, chapters, titlesec, report

im  trying to get my chapter numbers printed as text, but on the way there i messed up my section numbers with  text "ONE" and "TWO" an such,  here is what i was doing,

This code centers, pull up and changes font to normal size the chapter headings,
I needed to change chapter numbering to text i.e.  "CHAPTER 1" becomes "CHAPTER ONE". So far, I have the digit to text part figured out, but how to make the stuff uppercase and  stop it from tripping over the error  in the appendix that says `missing number treating as zero` i can not figure out.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\filcenter\normalsize\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}  %%%%  pull up chapter heading
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

how can i have uppercase "one" and such instead of chapter numbers in the chapter heading, without interfering with the table of contents and the section numbering?
i got all this from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29568/how-to-change-the-chapter-number-to-display-as-text-one-two) other question and  other places

Comment: Don't redefine `\thechapter`, but rather say `\NUMBERstring{chapter}` in `\titleformat`.

Answer (score 1):

From @egreg  comment this was what needed to  be changed:

```
  {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \NUMBERstring{\thechapter}}{10pt}{\filcenter\normalsize\MakeUppercase}
```