# change glossaries title to centered and appendix entry to letter in report

Tags: page-numbering, glossaries, appendices

As a follow up to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144817/get-chapter-numbers-as-text-in-the-report-class/144821#144821) i have two issues that have cropped up,

1. from my glossaries and titlesec setup my glossaries are `section` type, and 
   my titleformat flushes left section titles, so is it possible to have these glossaries titles centered?
2. The other is that due to my change from numbers ie "CHAPTER 1" to text 
   i.e "CHAPTER ONE", my appendix now behaves funny, in the table of contents we have  appendix A and B,  but in the body its called `Appendix ONE` and `Appendix TWO`   how can i change this back to  letters `A` and `B`?

here is some minimal part of the preamble.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,toc,section]{glossaries}   
\newglossary[alg]{acronymlist}{acr}{acn}{ACRONYMS}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
\newglossary[abg]{abbrevlist}{abi}{ayg}{GLOSSARY}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
   {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \NUMBERstring{chapter}}{10pt}{\filcenter\normalsize\MakeUppercase}
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt} 
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i cheated, but, it works, here goes:

for issue 1: i  added this just before the glossary/acronymlist

```
 \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\filcenter} {\thesection}{1em}{}
```

and this just after to undo that:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} {\thesection}{1em}{}
```

For  issue 2, i added the following just before the `\appendix` command

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
                                {\filcenter\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt} 
                                {\filcenter\normalsize\MakeUppercase}
```

end of problems