# How to print chapter cardinal number instead of integer with titlesec

Tags: numbering, titles, chapters

Am using the book environment and trying to print the chapter title as "Chapter One", instead of "Chapter 1".
I've searched about the "cardinal" and "chapter", but I didn't find anything similar to what I want.

The problem is that am using the titlesec package:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside,a4paper]{book} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)
\usepackage{graphics}
\graphicspath{ {images/} } % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[font=large]{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=large]{caption}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{PaleGreen}{HTML}{E6E6E6}

\usepackage{manyfoot}       % NOTE: manyfoot and DeclareNewFootnote MUST be declared before the BibLatex package,
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}      % otherwise, you get an error about no room for a new counter
                            % Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            backref=false,
            style=ieee,
            citereset=chapter,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=100,
            block=none]{biblatex}
%%%%%%%%%
% the command \sbc (short bracketed cite) defined below prints footnote citation with brackets
\newcommand{\sbc}[1]{\bfcite{#1}}           
%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{10pt}}
\definecolor{chapterSepLine}{HTML}{41B6c4}
\definecolor{chapterNumColor}{HTML}{212121}
\newcommand{\blackTBar}{{\color{black}\titlerule[0.75pt]}}
\newcommand{\royalBlueTBar}{{\color{chapterSepLine}\titlerule[0.75pt]}}

%--------- Chapter heading format ---------
\titleformat{\chapter}
[hang] % shape
{\center\LARGE\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont}   % format
{{\color{chapterNumColor} {\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}} % label
{0pt}   % sep
{\center\Huge\bfseries }    % before
[\hrule\vspace{1pt}\royalBlueTBar]  % after
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-35pt}{40pt} % \titlespacing[*]{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}[<right-sep>]

%--------- Section heading format ---------
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{
    \usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont} % bch for Bitstream Charter, and ppl for Palatino
    {} 
    {0em}
    {\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}}

%--------- Subsection heading format ---------
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{
    \usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont} % bch for Bitstream Charter, and ppl for Palatino
    {} 
    {0em}
    {\hspace{-0.4pt}\large \thesubsection\hspace{0.6em}}

%--------- paragraph heading format ---------
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{
    \usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont} % bch for Bitstream Charter, and ppl for Palatino
    {} 
    {0em}
    {\hspace{-0.4pt}\large\hspace{0.6em}}


\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\usepackage{inconsolata}                % monofont only, which replaces the current mono (Libertine) font

\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}{ \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \Numberstring{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fmtcount}%

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%   BEGIN DOCUMENT
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The package `fmtcount` might help, but the precise solution depends on the class. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the chapter number to display as text (One, Two, ...)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29568/how-to-change-the-chapter-number-to-display-as-text-one-two)

Comment: I added an MWE, am using the titlesec package, which is just like forbids the use of cardinal numbering in the chapter

Comment: While the standard `chapter number display` might be a duplicate, the usage of the `titlesec` does not make it duplicate of the question linked to by egreg... however, it might be a duplicate of some other question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a quick solution for `book.cls`, but this does not affect the page chaptermark headings.

The `book` class uses the command`\@makechapterhead` for setting the chapter heading via `\@chapapp\space \thechapter`. Replacing this by a patch by

`\@chapapp\space \Numberstring{chapter}`

`Chapter 1` will be `Chapter One` etc.

The macro `\Numberstring` from `fmtcount` package expects a counter name and uses the corresponding verbal expression of the number.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}{ \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \Numberstring{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fmtcount}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note* The `\xpatchcmd` macro has two final arguments for the successful or failing patching of a command... I omitted code for this ;-)

### New version, with the MWE from the OP

The chapter format has to be changed from

```
{{\color{chapterNumColor} {\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}} % label
```

to this

```
{{\color{chapterNumColor} {\chaptertitlename}~\Numberstring{chapter}}} % label



\documentclass[12pt, oneside,a4paper]{book} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)
\usepackage{graphics}
\graphicspath{ {images/} } % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[font=large]{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=large]{caption}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{PaleGreen}{HTML}{E6E6E6}

\usepackage{manyfoot}       % NOTE: manyfoot and DeclareNewFootnote MUST be declared before the BibLatex package,
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}      % otherwise, you get an error about no room for a new counter
                            % Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            backref=false,
            style=ieee,
            citereset=chapter,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=100,
            block=none]{biblatex}
%%%%%%%%%
% the command \sbc (short bracketed cite) defined below prints footnote citation with brackets
\newcommand{\sbc}[1]{\bfcite{#1}}           
%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this
\usepackage{fmtcount}%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{10pt}}
\definecolor{chapterSepLine}{HTML}{41B6c4}
\definecolor{chapterNumColor}{HTML}{212121}
\newcommand{\blackTBar}{{\color{black}\titlerule[0.75pt]}}
\newcommand{\royalBlueTBar}{{\color{chapterSepLine}\titlerule[0.75pt]}}

%--------- Chapter heading format ---------
\titleformat{\chapter}
[hang] % shape
{\center\LARGE\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont}   % format
{{\color{chapterNumColor} {\chaptertitlename}~\Numberstring{chapter}}} % label
{0pt}   % sep
{\center\Huge\bfseries }    % before
[\hrule\vspace{1pt}\royalBlueTBar]  % after
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-35pt}{40pt} % \titlespacing[*]{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}[<right-sep>]

%--------- Section heading format ---------
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{
    \usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont} % bch for Bitstream Charter, and ppl for Palatino
    {} 
    {0em}
    {\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}}

%--------- Subsection heading format ---------
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{
    \usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont} % bch for Bitstream Charter, and ppl for Palatino
    {} 
    {0em}
    {\hspace{-0.4pt}\large \thesubsection\hspace{0.6em}}

%--------- paragraph heading format ---------
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{
    \usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont} % bch for Bitstream Charter, and ppl for Palatino
    {} 
    {0em}
    {\hspace{-0.4pt}\large\hspace{0.6em}}


\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\usepackage{inconsolata}                % monofont only, which replaces the current mono (Libertine) font

\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}{ \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \Numberstring{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother


\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%   BEGIN DOCUMENT
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added an MWE, am using the titlesec package, which is just like forbids the use of cardinal numbering in the chapter

Comment: @blueMix: Well, I provided my solution before you posted your 'MWE'. You should have stated the `titlesec` usage right from the start of the post

Comment: \usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}

Comment: @blueMix: This will change any numbering of chapters, your sections will be displayed as `One.1` and in the TOC this will appear 'wrong' as well.

Comment: Really?! I don't want this :), just try to execute the MWE code, and you still see the integer number, because of the titlesec.

Comment: @blueMix: Just see my updated answer