# fancyhdr novel's pages need headers with CHAPTER ONE, TWO etc. spelled out

Tags: header-footer, memoir, fancyhdr, python, scrbook

I'd like to use the fancyhdr package to have odd number pages with the chapter number spelled out, for instance, "CHAPTER ONE" OR "CHAPTER TWO" etc., and the even number pages with the actually title of the chapter, for instance, "ESCAPE FROM DARTHAN"

So far, I've learned that the package contains these macro commands.
\thechapter generates the chapter number, for instance 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.  \chaptername generates the word "Chapter" 
\chaptermark generates the title

Since this is a literary work, I'd like it to appear less technical, and use words instead of numbers.  It's common in popularly published novels to do that, so I hope LaTeX has that capability.

FYI, Koma Script Book Class scrbook doesn't use the fancyhdr package for headers, but has it's own macros book headers that might be able to solve it. I believe the Memoir Class does use fancyhdr package for book headers though.

Is there a way I can get \thechapter to print ONE, TWO, THREE etc?  Or, is there another LaTeX way I can do that, perhaps using the scrbook or memoir class?

Comment: See [How to change the chapter number to display as text (One, Two, …)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29568/5764)

Comment: If the linked post doesn't solve your problem, please provide the community with a [minimal example](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) using dummy text from [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum).

Comment: *What* class are you using? It can't be both `memoir` or `scrbook` (and neither uses `fancyhdr`).

Comment: I'm testing my book out with these classes: book, memoir and scrbook.  I'm using LyX (you can easily just swap the class out under the Document/Settings/Class menu)  I haven't had any luck with the code supplied in similar thread.. cut and paste into the preamble didn't work, the code too unfamiliar and complex for me to tweak or customize.  I need a simply solution that doesn't require a lot of nested macros or packages to understand.  I do know a little Python, with that package I hope to build a For Loop to iterate a List [One, Two, etc].. just need to keep the List alive each time called.

Comment: and.. the Page Layout is set under LyX Document/Settings to Heading Style: "Fancy"..just assumed it was using the fancyhdr package, which the BOOK class uses.  I'm trying to learn the fancyhdr package to add LaTeX code manually within LyX, but it doesn't have the option for chapter ONE, TWO etc.  BTW, my novel is setup with Child Files: Chapters. Parent document contains Front Matter, TOC, calls child Chapters. The book has NOTHING complex, all centered or \microtype justified text, a TOC, Chapters, Scene Break lines.  Odd Header: CHAPTER ONEetc. Even Header: CH TITLE, centered Footer=page

Comment: This is quite a lot of text, but *no* helpful information at all. Neither of the mentioned classes *uses `fancyhdr`* (not even book). `fancyhdr` is just *one* of the classes able to do headers/footers, but KOMA *and* memoir have their own stuff. Decide for *one* document class now, change the appearance later. Everything can be done with every class, but they differ in workforce. Stuff that can be easily achieved with KOMA *or* memoir, can be quite hard using `book`. Is python  relevant here? Please add a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/)

Comment: I'm going settle on the KOMA Scirpt Book class (scrbook) and whatever other packages necessary to generate the headers and footers.  Whichever is the simplest method would work best for me, it's just that I don't know how to solve the problem using any solution at all.  (I understand there's probably a dozen ways it could be done)  So, can anyone tell me if the /Forloop macro could do what I need, in combination with fancyhdr perhaps, to generate a CHAPTER ONE, TWO etc header on odd pages only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think, this question is a duplicate to @egreg's answer.

We use `scrlayer-scrpage` with some of the newest features, so an up to date TeX-distribution is needed.

We first clear all the predefined fields (1), remove the chapter number from the our left pages (2), put the leftmark, which is our chaptertitle, in the center of even pages (3). Put the name of the chapter and the spelled out number (using package `fmtcount`) in the center of odd pages (4), add a page number in the footers center. We set the header to use small caps on the right place (5).

Later we define a command, that just prints some dummy text for testing.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\clearpairofpagestyles%1
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{}%2
\cohead{\leftmark}%3
\cehead{\chapapp\ \numberstring{chapter}}(4)
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
%page number on all pages
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\scshape}%5
%small caps headers, make it more *novelly*
\newcommand{\dasEnte}[1]{\chapter{#1}\blindtext[10]}
% i don't want ducks to die
\begin{document}
\dasEnte{Donald}
\dasEnte{Daisy}
\dasEnte{Gustav}
\dasEnte{Tic}
\appendix
\dasEnte{Mickey}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's what I needed, particularly the fmtcount package and it's \numberstring macro.  It turns out LyX is using the fancyhdr package with my Komo-Script, instead of the more extensive scrlayer-scrpage.  I'll be able to tweak just right now.

Comment: You can put things in the preamble of your document. Just copy the code and don't use the clicky interface. LaTeX is the base, doing nearly everything. LyX is the level for advanced users, downside: Less flexibility.

Comment: alright, I had gotten it in there just fine. I had taken the code, pasted into a text editor as example.tex, then opened a blank .lyx file, did a File>Import>[Plain Text] of example.tex.  LyX processed it: took the Preamble code and put it in its settings place,and the other code visible within the document processor interface.  I've added a title page, TOC and page footer: \cfoot{\pagemark} and changed the capitalization to smallcaps to suit me for the headers: \cohead{\textsc{\leftmark}}
\cehead{\textsc{\chapapp\ \Numberstring{chapter}}} It's looking great, like a literary novel should now.

Comment: can you explain to me the options in \newcommand.  I understand it's defining and populating the chapter with dummy text, but I don't understand what "[1]" and "{#1}" do.  Also the \renewcommand, I can't grasp why I need to use renewcommand.

Comment: @user12711 We define a command `dasEnte` with exactly one needed argument `[1]`. In the definition, we use this argument with `#1`. If we call `\dasEnte{Donald}`; LaTeX replaces it with `\chapter{Donald}\blindtext[10]`. Should be explained in any LaTeX introduction.

Comment: Your LyX workflow seems quite complicated.

Comment: I'm going to be sharpening my LaTeX skills using Kile.  I can easily see the potential of what all can be done with LyX, so it may be helpful for me to bounce back and forth.  I'm impressed with both LyX and Kile in their own way, Kile for understanding the Code, and LyX for potential streamlining and organizing.  In the longterm, I'm not sure which I'll settle on permanently for my projects... but that's probably another thread.  I do want to get the MOST STREAMLINED methodology down pat.  That's why I'm using LaTeX, and taking the pains to learn it now.

Comment: Learning LaTeX isn't a pain ;-) btw: Even if you stick with LyX, you will need to use some LaTeX Code once in a while.

Comment: +1 for `\cohead{\leftmark}`. Now I can dynamically redefine `\markleft`, and it's so good!