# How to make chapter number appear as a written number instead of an Arabic number?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

I am using the memoir class. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "written number?" Thirteen as opposed to 13?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to obtain "Chapter One" instead of "Chapter 1", etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to change the chapter number to display as text (One, Two, …)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29568/5764)

Comment: I've tried the top solution but I got the Undefined control sequence error. Since I was using memoir I tried the second solution which recommended me to go take a look at the documentation on chapter 6.5.1. But even after more than 45 minutes of going through that section, I couldn't find the right code. The examples were all about removing the chapter name, there was no such thing for replacing the "1" by "one".

Comment: What about adding to your preamble the following: `\usepackage{fmtcount} \newcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \Numberstring{chapter}}` Does that solve your problem?