# multipart node to represent a byte

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am trying to create a multipart node to represent a byte

I wish I could write
`\Byte{0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0}` or `\Byte {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}` and obtain 
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\newcommand{\Byte}{
\node [rectangle split,rectangle split parts=8, rectangle split horizontal,draw ] at (2,2)
{\nodepart{one}0\nodepart{two}1\nodepart{three}0\nodepart{four}0\nodepart{five}1\nodepart{six}1\nodepart{seven}0\nodepart{eight}0};
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Byte
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with the second of your desired invocations wherein we use a `\foreach` to built the node contents and thus prepare the node before calling it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67923/86}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\def\numtext#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or eight\or nine\or ten\or
eleven\or twelve\or thirteen\or fourteen\or fifteen\or sixteen\or seventeen\or eighteen\or nineteen\or twenty\or Lots\fi}

\newcommand{\Byte}[1]{
\def\nodecontents{}%
\foreach[count=\l] \k in {#1} {
    \xappto{\nodecontents}{\noexpand\nodepart{\numtext{\l}}\k}
}
\node [rectangle split,rectangle split parts=8, rectangle split horizontal,draw ] at (2,2)
{\nodecontents};
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Byte {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: multibyte TikZ command]

Comment: There is a `fmtcount` package for that. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/convert-any-number-to-corresponding-word

Comment: @percusse Sadly, not expandably - at least, not with my simple tests.  So I can't use it inside the expansion step.

Comment: oops.didn't test it sorry.

Comment: @percusse Don't apologise.  I didn't know of that package so I've learnt something that I'm sure I'll use someday.

Comment: Merci, I use this answer

Answer (score 10):

Using `\def` you can write things like `\Byte(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\def\Byte(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8){
\node [rectangle split,rectangle split parts=8, rectangle split horizontal,draw ] at (2,2)
{\nodepart{one}#1\nodepart{two}#2\nodepart{three}#3\nodepart{four}#4\nodepart{five}#5\nodepart{six}#6\nodepart{seven}#7\nodepart{eight}#8};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Byte(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: merci, I try it

Comment: can we use \newcommand instead of \def?

Comment: @rpapa `\newcommand` doesn't allow for delimited arguments, `\def` does.

Comment: @rpapa No we cannot, since the command has a special formatting (the arguments are seperated by commas instead of put in braces). With `\newcommand` only the default is possible.