# Page numbering in words

Tags: page-numbering

How is one supposed to number pages in words?

eg: 1 → 'Page one'

- `\pagenumbering{style}` does not provide an option for full words.
- [Ctan](http://www.ctan.org/topic/page-nos) under the category page numberring (page-nos) does not have any package which numbers the pages in words.

Comment: See [Convert any number to corresponding word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/convert-any-number-to-corresponding-word) for several solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to the problem can be achieved using

- [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) : custom headers and footers
- [fmtcount](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) : format a counter to a variety of formats (including the english word)

These packages will be used as follows :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fmtcount}%Page number to full english
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%Header and footer

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{} % No header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%No ruler
\fancyfoot[CE, CO] {\textit{Page \numberstringnum{\thepage}}}%Print Page and convert page number

\usepackage{lipsum}%Dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-35]%Dummy text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or `\numberstring{page}`