# Howto format "Edition" in bibliography with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I use `biblatex` and `biber`. I want "edition" part of my bibliography appears "edisi pertama","edisi kedua","edisi ketiga",etc instead of "1st edition","2nd edition","3rd edition",etc. I have successfully changed "edition" to "edisi" and but how to put it before "pertama","kedua"...

UPDATED:
I write my thesis in separated latex files. Here is the main one:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\usepackage{uithesis}
\input{laporan_setting}
\begin{document}
\include{sampul}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{bab1}
\singlespacing
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And this is uithesis.sty:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{
 \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}
   \urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,headheight=0pt,headsep=2.5cm,footskip=1.4cm,
 left=4cm,top=4cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=up]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
   \floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop,objectset=centering,footskip=3.5pt}
   \floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,floatwidth=1.2\textwidth}
   \renewcommand\FBbskip{2pt} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[ConnyRevised]{fncychap}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
   \floatplacement{figure}{H}
   \floatplacement{table}{H}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{dafpus.bib}
 \bibitemsep .5cm
 \ifmorenames{true}
 \NewBibliographyString{in}
 \NewBibliographyString{and}
 \NewBibliographyString{bibliography}
 \NewBibliographyString{edition}
 \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    in = {dalam},
    and = {dan},
    bibliography = {Daftar Pustaka},
    edition = {edisi}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What kind of language is `edisi`? Is `\usepackage[yourlanguage]{babel}` not an option? Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Christian: It's bahasa, I just have edited my question

Comment: Your example is still not compilable for us. Also, I might add that it is not really minimal in the strictest (and probably not even in the loosest) sense of the word, the `.sty` file certainly contains a lot of packages  not at all related to the issue at hand (`changepage`, `fancyhdr`, `pgfplots` to name but a few randomly chosen ones, basically everything but `biblatex` and its commands and `babel`/`csquotes` is unnecessary).

Comment: You could go with `\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\ifinteger{#1}{\bibstring{edition}~\mkbibordedition{#1}}{#1\isdot}}` to have the word "edition" before the number, but you also seem to want to change any positive integer to a "word" which seems quite hard, but has been [implemented for some languages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28326/35864). The easiest way would probably be to just change the `edition` field to `edition = {edisi ketiga}`.

Comment: @moewe, Oh silly me, I just changed the edition field as you suggested and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to input the text as you want to see it into the `edition` field, for example

```
edition = {edisi ketiga}
```

This, of course, is not that automatic, as we would like it to be.
For some languages (where the word for edition does not vary with the number of the edition)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\bibstring{edition}~\mkbibordeditio‌​n{#1}}
    {#1\isdot}}
```

might suffice.
Here, the number stays an ordinal formatted as defined in the `.lbx` file.

There are some solutions to convert an integer into the corresponding words, see [Convert any number to corresponding word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28326/35864), you will have to go through great lengths though if there has to be some change of the word for "edition" depending on the value of the `edition` field.