# "Chapter one" instead of "Chapter 1"

Tags: titles, chapters

In my thesis, I want to use the statement "Chapter one" instead of "Chapter 1". Do I add specific changes into the following commands?

```
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vspace{5cm}\filcenter}
{\filcenter \LARGE\bfseries
\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
{1ex}
{\vspace*{5ex}\filcenter\Huge\bfseries}
[\vfill\clearpage]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to ensure the the `\ifcase` specification in the `\justwords` macro goes out far enough to include the largest chapter number.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vspace{5cm}\filcenter}
{\filcenter \LARGE\bfseries
\chaptertitlename\ \justwords{\thechapter}}
{1ex}
{\vspace*{5ex}\filcenter\Huge\bfseries}
[\vfill\clearpage]
\def\justwords#1{\ifcase#1 \or one\or two\or three\or four\or etc.\fi}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ABC}

\chapter{DEF}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Thanks to Willy for pointing out the `fmtcount` package already has this feature in the form of the `\numberstringnum` macro.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,fmtcount}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\vspace{5cm}\filcenter}
{\filcenter \LARGE\bfseries
\chaptertitlename\ \numberstringnum{\thechapter}}
{1ex}
{\vspace*{5ex}\filcenter\Huge\bfseries}
[\vfill\clearpage]
\begin{document}
\chapter{ABC}

\chapter{DEF}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And if one is too lazy to type out all the number names, [fret not, for someone else has already done it, in multiple languages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/convert-any-number-to-corresponding-word).