# Make a CV auto updating

Tags: calculations, calc

I would like to create a code to insert in my CV that make it auto update.

The hypotetic sentence is this one:

"Engineer with `twenty` experience years", where `twenty` is generated by, e.g., `\startyear{1997}`.

I have written this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}

\newcommand{\startyear}[1]{\SUBTRACT{\the\year}{1997}{\sol}\sol}

\begin{document}
    Engineer with \startyear{1997} experience years.
\end{document}
```

that returns:

*

### Engineer with 20 experience years.

*

But I would like the number (20) in text.

Comment: after a quick google: the `fmtcount`package might be helpful

Comment: No need to use the `calculator` package here. `\newcommand{\startyear}[1]{\the\numexpr\year-#1}`

Comment: And with `fmtcount` as @daleif suggested: `\newcommand{\startyear}[1]{\numberstringnum{\numexpr\year-#1}}`

Comment: With `\usepackage{fmtcount}` and `\newcommand{\startyear}[1]{\numberstringnum{\numexpr\year-#1‌​}}` in the preamble, I obtain the output: "**Engineer with twenty experience years.**", but with the error: "**Missing = inserted for \ifnum. Engineer with \startyear{1997}**" in the line where I use `\startyear{1997}`.

Comment: Isn't this nearly a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/convert-any-number-to-corresponding-word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The calculation is pretty easy with `\the\numexpr\year-#1` where `#1` is considered to hold the number of the starting year.

This is fed into `\numberstringnum` which 'translates' the number into the number word, i.e. `1` would become `one` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fmtcount}


\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\startyear}[1]{\numberstringnum{\the\numexpr\year-#1}}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1900,...,\the\year} {
    Engineer with \startyear{\x}\ experience years. 

  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I confirm that the code compile with and without the `the` command in `newcommand` and in `\foreach`.